# Is there any way to tell vim to highlight any asterisks preceded by a type?

Tags: vim

...without having to define regex matches for each one of the types.
Eg match the following:

```
char *ch
char* ch 
char **ch 
char*  ** *ch 
char **
ch
```

In the above example I want everything but *ch* to be highlighted.
Currently I specify a regex match for each type individually:

```
syn match cType "char[*[:space:]\n]*[[:space:]\n][*[:space:]\n]*"
```

...but this way I resort in having to modify all the syntax files myself.

Comment: I know about https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic but I don't know about custom rules, you should dig into it.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to modify an existing syntax group to append matching text, so you have to override or redefine the `cType` definitions.

#### approach 1

If you define a separate `cTypeAsterisks` group that matches the `*` / whitespace combinations (and specify `contained` so that it doesn't match on its own in the wrong places), all you have to do is augment the `cType` definitions with `nextgroup=cTypeAsterisks skipwhite`.

That still means duplicating all the `cType` definitions from `syntax/c.vim`, though it possibly could be done dynamically with meta-programming (i.e. parsing the `:syn list cType` output, modifying, and re-executing it).

#### approach 2

You can make overriding the `cType` group easier / reduce duplication by specifying all types in regular expression branches, like this:

```
syn match cType "\%(char\|int\|long\|short\|void\)[*[:space:]\n]*[[:space:]\n][*[:space:]\n]*"
```

#### approach 3

Though this isn't 100% correct, you can define a separate `cTypeAsterisks` group, and just assert that it matches after a general pattern for C types (e.g. `\w\+\s*`). This would also erroneously highlight things like `foo **`, but it's easy and doesn't require duplication.

Comment: It appears though, that approach 3 apart from c pointers would match multiplications as well.

Comment: Correct. But C syntax is so complex that the regexp-based approach will never be 100% correct, anyway.

Comment: I just found out that approach 1 doesn't work either: syn match cTypeAsterisks "[*[:space:]\n]*[[:space:]\n][*[:space:]\n]*" contained
syn match Type "char" nextgroup=cTypeAsterisks skipwhite. It highlights only "char" and not the asterisks.